# Can't Chroot into archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, chroot, arm, busybox, arch-arm

I have Installed the generic aarch64 rootfs to an sdcard , and have placed It inside my phone and am trying to chroot into it - via a superuser adb shell , by running `busybox chroot /data/local/mnt /bin/bash`

however - I get `chroot: can't execute '/bin/bash': No such file or directory`

Comment: It's looking for `/bin/bash` in the `chroot`ed filesystem. Does `/data/local/mnt/bin/bash` (and all its shared libraries) exist?

Comment: @waltinator yes it does